# Cant access JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

im trying to access the ID and SENT from this JSON but is not working for me.

**UPDATED**

```
$json = '{
 "response": {
  "sent": true,
  "message": "Sent to 57304",
  "id": "gBEGVzBChXFYAgmcOrfFpGem8qw"
 }
}';

json_decode($json);

$id=$json->id;
$sent=$json->sent;

echo "</br> id:".$id."</br>";
echo "</br> sent:".$sent."</br>";
```

Comment: You need to wrap the json string in `json_decode()`

Comment: @mulquin just updated and still not working with json_decode()

Comment: Next time you can var_export($json) to see what it has and discover your mistake. That's the debug way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the php `json_decode()` function. Like this:

```
$json = '{
   "response": {
   "sent": true,
   "message": "Sent to 57304",
   "id": "gBEGVzBChXFYAgmcOrfFpGem8qw"
   }
}';

$json = json_decode($json, true);
$json = (object) $json['response'];
echo $json->sent;  // output: 1
echo $json->id;    // output: "gBEGVzBChXFYAgmcOrfFpGem8qw"
```

> 1 is the equivalent for a boolean value of true

Comment: Thank a lot this worked !

Comment: Nothing is happening, I'm glad it works for you. @Andres Carvajal

Answer (score 0):

It Works,There are two label of JSON object,so you cant access inner object directly. you should assign json_decode($json) into a php object like $obj=json_decode($json); here is the working file

```js
<?php
$json = '{
        "response": {
                    "sent": true,
                    "message": "Sent to 57304",
                    "id": "gBEGVzBChXFYAgmcOrfFpGem8qw"
                    }
        }';
   // convert assign json data into php object
   $obj=json_decode($json);
   //All the inner key can be access throug 'response' object
   $id=$obj->response->id;
   $sent=$obj->response->sent;
   
   
   echo "</br> id:".$id."</br>";
   echo "</br> sent:".$sent."</br>";
```